# What does this use of the '&&' operator mean in C++?

Tags: c++, logic, operators, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am working on a project to implement a Binary Search Tree, root is a pointer to a Node struct, and I ran into a piece of code online with the following line:

```
if ((root->left) && (root->right))
```

is the code above equivalent to:

```
if (root->left == root->right)
```

if not can someone please explain the difference to me? I thought you needed to have some sort of comparative operator (==, !=).

Comment: No, it is equivalent to `if (root.left != 0 && root->right != 0)`. The inner parentheses are redundant.

Comment: @user207421 and writing that we need to use -Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-constant with g++ and clang to avoid warnings when left and right are pointers.

Comment: `&&` means different things in different contexts.  It can be a _logical and_, a template _forwarding reference_ parameter (sometimes called a _universal reference_ due to Scott Meyers early nomenclature), or a _rvalue reference_ (when it isn't a template parameter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not post the code (and in C++ lot of things depend on context) but I believe that:

```
if ((root->left) && (root->right))
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if ((root->left != nullptr) && (root->right != nullptr))
```

The pointers in C++ can be implicitly converted to `bool` that is `true` when the pointer is a non-null pointer. The `&&` operator means 'and'.   So for the `if` condition to be `true`, both `root->left` *and* `root->right` are non-null pointers.

The relevant part from standard [conv.bool]

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value,
>   null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to
>   false; any other value is converted to true. For direct-initialization
>   , a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type bool; the resulting value is false.

Comment: Sorry about not posting code but this cleared things up for me. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: *Anything* appearing as a logical-expression acts as `true` if non-zero and `false` if zero. It has nothing to do with pointers specifically. Or `bool` either, which is just a kludge on top of this fact.

Comment: @user207421 C++ standard explicitly tells about zero value, null pointer value and null member pointer value so it would be incorrect from me to simplify and to conflate those under dim concepts of  "zero" versus "nonzero". I already told that I just guessed that in OP's code there were pointers under question.

Comment: You're cherry-picking the standard.   Other sections of the standard specify that a integer literal with value zero is a null pointer constant.  As such, the comment by @user207421 is a valid interpretation.   It's not exactly unusual for some sections of the standard to split hairs differently from other sections - particularly in recent standards, which seem to be allowing language lawyers excessive freedom to play.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Is there anything in the section you refer to about `bool`? And is there really nothing elsewhere that says the same applies to all primitive types?

Comment: @Peter C++ is statically typed.and standard keeps clear differences between zeroes, null pointers and false. Literal with value zero is indeed null pointer constant to support backwards compatibility with C and earlier C++ code, however constant expression with value zero like (1-1) is not null pointer nor implicitly convertible to such. Also modern compilers tend to warn when 0 instead of nullptr is used as null pointer constant.

Comment: @user207421 yes the paragraph is about how types can be converted to bool. If statement [stmt.if] needs a condition expression that yields to true or false, inbuilt operator&& in [over.built] is bool operator&&(bool, bool). Unless the undiclosed code of OP had overloaded operator&& and surprizing types of left and right I trust that I correctly guessed what is going on in my answer.